# How to Set Exchange Body When Using Apache Camel JXPath Expression Language

Tags: apache-camel

I need to test whether the predicate object matches the exchange for various expression languages. I need to know what exchange value I need to set in exchange to validate the predicate.

```
public void test() { 
   String expression="//orders/value>10"'; 
   CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
   Predicate predicate=new JXpathExpression(expression,boolean.class); 
   Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(context); 
   Message in = exchange.getIn(); 
   in.setBody(""); // how i need to set the message in exchange in order to evaluate it against predicate 
   exchange.setIn(in); 
   boolean check=predicate.matches(exchange); 
}
```

For JXPath the predicate object contains `JXpath[//orders/value>10]` when I print it using `predicate.toString()`.

How do I set the exchange so that this expression can be validated?

Comment: Also posted on Camel user mailing list: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Expression-Language-exchange-test-td5633420.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JXPath works on java objects. So you have to set a suitable object in the message body.
If the object you set there has o.getOrders().getValue() and returns a numeric value > 10 then the predicate should evaluate to true.